# Hindu marriage and moksha

Tags: marriage, moksha

It is said that a Hindu marriage binds the groom and the bride for seven janmas.

Now, suppose I get married in this janma. If immediately after this janma (or the next, or the next to next) I attain moksha, that means I become free from the cycle of birth and rebirth. But then, I can no longer be married to that person in subsequent janmas because I would have no more janmas after moksha.

These two things seem incompatible then. Does this mean married people cannot attain moksha at least till the next seven janmas? Is lifelong Brahmacharya then a prerequisite for moksha?

PS: I know there are many forms of moksha. I am not talking about all of them. I am specifically asking about the kind of moksha that leads to the end of the cycle of rebirths.

Comment: marriage binds for 7 births only IF you take birth. also, you don't know if this is your 1st or 7th time marrying this person.